# How to downgrade React-Native to use React version 15.*

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have RN and Web application in the same folder, so the both use the same node_modules. My web application was written with react 15 and the latest RN uses react 16-alpha. My issue is: how to use two versions of React for different platform or how to downgrade RN to use React 15. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4723 solved my problem. Installed older version of RN